Mypy complains about poetry packages I included from the project subdirectories in src
Here is my poetry packages in my pyproject.py:
packages = [
    {include = "api", from = "src"},
    {include = "another_api", from = "src"},
    {include = "infra"}
]

And when I import some symbol in my api package like from api.constants import BEST_MYPY_QUESTION, I get the typical error of:
src/api/main.py:1: error: Skipping analyzing "api.constants": module is installed, but missing library stubs or py.typed marker  [import-untyped]

Here is my code in src/api/main.py
from api.constants import BEST_MYPY_QUESTION

print(BEST_MYPY_QUESTION)

The usual way to solve such error is to run mypy with --ignore-missing-imports option set, however, I don't like to do that because this should be type checked as I already have the source code to check against.

Package is considered typed if and only if it contains py.typed in its root. I'm not sure where it should be in your specific case of multiple packages - either touch src/api/py.typed or touch py.typed, assuming that pyproject.toml is in your CWD. Also, how do you invoke mypy? It may be caused by wrong CWD or command arguments as well.

I run mypy in my project root where src directory and my pyproject.toml file exists:
mypy . --explicit-package-bases --check-untyped-defs
